# install Jupyter in conda env - "AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'"

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, conda

when i run the command conda install jupyter Anaconda prompt(miniconda3) the prompt says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in 
    sys.exit(main())

File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 149, in main
    from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler

File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 25, in 
    from .common.io import dashlist, timeout

File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 33, in 
    from .._vendor.tqdm import tqdm

File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\tqdm__init__.py", line 8, in 
    from ._tqdm import tqdm

File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\tqdm_tqdm.py", line 13, in 
    from ._utils import _supports_unicode, _environ_cols_wrapper, _range, _unich, \

File "C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\tqdm_utils.py", line 31, in 
    colorama.init()

AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevanttags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with `colorama 0.4.6`. If you look at the [issue here](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/370) on their github repo, the solution is to import colorama using `from colorama import initialise`. You will have to go into your `anaconda3\envs\CARLA\Lib\site-packages\jupyter` files where colorama.init() is called and change the import statement. Usually this will be in the utils.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the issue fix (at least for me - comment if it works for you).

How to fix it:

Download Colorama
Copy the "Colorama" from the download then replace the folder named "colorama" in C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

I suspect this issue occurs because of ([issue 8842](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8842))

Comment: i switched to anaconda and then i didn't have to go through all this.